# Change value input onclick witch setTimeout

Tags: javascript, button, input, settimeout

How can I remove special symbols (R$) when clicking the button, or simply remove if it exists?

```
setTimeout(function clean() {
var input = document.getElementById('value')
input.value = input.value.replace(/[!$(){}[\]:;R<+?\\>]/g,'')
},3000)
```

I would like that when clicking on the button, it would also remove the symbol R$

I have so far

```js
setTimeout(function clean() {
var input = document.getElementById('value')
onclick = input.value = input.value.replace(/[!$(){}[\]:;R<+?\\>]/g,'')
}, 2000)
```

```html
<input id="value" name="item_valor" value="R$ 14,99" >
remover simbolo pagseguro
<br>

<button class="" onclick="clean()">clean</button>
```

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time, making your question here unanswerable. Instead, post your relevant code right here in your question as a Stack Snippet (the `<>` icon while you are editing your question, as I have done for you.

Comment: tanks man! perfect work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method and then the `String.trim()` method to ensure there are no leading or trailing spaces left behind..

```js
const input = document.getElementById("value");
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  input.value = input.value.replace("R$","").trim();
});
```

```html
<input id="value" name="item_valor" value="R$ 14,99" >
remover simbolo pagseguro
<br>

<button>clean</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex for removing the special symbol is right,
only error was of setTimeout & function declaration error.

I have fixed that code error.

Below snippet will work, but in function clean() it will wait for 1000ms because of setTimeout function.

```js
function clean() {
  setTimeout(()=>{
    var input = document.getElementById('value')
    onclick = input.value = input.value.replace(/[!$(){}[\]:;R<+?\\>]/g,'');
    input.value = input.value.trim();
  }, 1000) // code inside setTimeout function will wait 1000ms to execute
}
```

```html
<input id="value" name="item_valor" value="R$ 14,99" >
remover simbolo pagseguro
<br>

<button class="" onclick="clean()">clean</button>
```

Comment: Tanks Man, work perfect